# how to create a custom private browser without toolbar (chromium or firefox)

Tags: firefox, browser, private, chromium

I want to have a standalone private browser setup with just 1 url and not toolbar.
Also I want to re-brand this a bit. 
in the early days I used xulrunner to do this, but could not find a good alternative for this.
I also want to open the browser in a custom space, so private from other browser session.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add the `-app=http://www.google.com` to the command line of chromium, it will load the URL without any toolbar ui.

eg. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=http://www.google.com`

[image: Chrome app without tool Ui]